# What is the correct way to link a git repo without merging it

Tags: git, merge

I want to have the main code of a website dev in one code-repo, and the content (pictures and other uploads) in another. A cron job would also backup the content into that content-repo.

So as a developer, I would want to clone the code-repo and optionally also the content-repo.

But a commit would only be required on the code-repo.

reading about submodules and subtrees and branches, I am not even sure, if those are the correct way to do it. As I understand it, it will always merge the files into the parent repo, my code-repo.

How could the separation and handling be done correctly/best?

Comment: "and the content (pictures and other uploads) in another"—generally speaking, content doesn't belong in version control. There are lots of reasons for this, but the simplest are that it just doesn't make sense (why should all copies of a repo have the same content?) and isn't necessary (why complicate things?). Why do you want to put this in a Git repository?

Comment: It absolutely eases things. The server can commit ("backup") frequently the changes of the content authors (which can be undone or tracked), the devs can get the content if needed - they might not, if only working on the code parts with placeholders. Or trying functions to kick the content around. So this is supreme to any file-copy-method. I have no idea, why you would not version control content. I do use it on psd files as well as cad files and surely on word docs, excel sheets and code files. Using at least owncloud (feels like using SVN - dupes and merging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using submodules works perfect. Using this, there is only a "reference" file that gets updated in the main repo. The submodule repo occupies a folder, that it tracks itself.
Any changes and files are ignored by the main repo.
E.g. SourceTree asks on main repo commit, if you want to commit the submodule repo first - if there were any changes.

This way, this is a perfect solution.

See my comment on my question, for how I use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you think submodules don't fit your needs you should check [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/). Using git-lfs you would have just one repo with all your source and content files. The only difference would be that content files are not directly stored within the repo and blowing it's size. Locally everything is there, but on the remote site content files in the repo would be handled as kind of pointer to the file and the file itself is stored within the large file storage.

Comment: The cron job would then need to commit to the main repo - which should not happen.

Comment: You are talking about user uploads not website content provided by the developer, right?

Comment: Yes, those uploads and admin content changes being committed to a content-repo by a cron job frequently right from the webserver dir - not including any code files (in case the server gets hacked and keeping the maincode-repo small).

Comment: But like that submodules could make sense. The status of the content repo as submodule of the main repo is tracked via the commit hash in the `.gitattributes`. Your cron job could do just the commits in the content repo and for your development locally you can select the version of the content repo that should be used. Every time you are deploying a new version of your code you cound use the latest content repo commit.

Comment: As I understood this, the files of a submodule will also be committed?

Comment: Yes, the only additional content in your main repo you will have using submodules is the entry in the `.gitattributes` file.